# Search Query for Multiple Terms In Same Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, search, terms, query-string

I have a search that works fine with custom fields, and one term per taxonomy. However I want to select multiple terms from one taxonomy "property-type".

My current query looks like ---

```
/?s=Search&property_city=Any+City&property_state=Any+State&address=&beds=Any&baths=Any&min_price=Any&max_price=Any&property_type=condo&property_type=duplex&min_area=Any&max_area=Any&post_type=property&hide-reports=list-property&property-contract-type=for-sale
```

I need this to use OR operator when selecting multiple terms --

```
 property_type=condo&property_type=duplex
```

Like so -

```
property_type=condo,duplex
```

Currently in my theme's functions  --

```
 $s = $_GET['s'];
                 $meta_query=array();
            if ($s == __('Search', 'framework')) {
                $query->set('s', '');
            }
              $query->set('post_type', 'property');
              $query->set('post_status','publish');
              if (!empty($property_type)) {
               $query->set('property-type', $property_type);
                }
                if (!empty($property_city)) {
               $query->set('city-type',$property_city);
                }
if (!empty($property_neighborhood)) {
               $query->set('neighborhood',$property_neighborhood);
                }
              if (!empty($property_contract_type)) {
                 $query->set('property-contract-type', $property_contract_type);
                }
```

Full Code -
https://pastebin.com/LC96j4v5

On my form -

```
<select name="property_type" class="form-control" multiple>
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0  ){
echo "<option class='button' value='Any'>All</option>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         echo "<option class='button' value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
     }
 }
?>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make only one change in the form, change the first line to:

```
<select name="property_type[]" class="form-control" multiple>
```

Name of the field has to include [] to be considered as an array when it arrives on the server side. In the query string it will be listed as:

```
property_type[]=condo&property_type[]=duplex
```

And, on server side, when you read this use this:

```
$property_type = (array)$_GET['property_type'];
```

This can go right at the top just after the `$s = $_GET['s'];` line,

Make sure to sanitize all the input data before using. More on data sanitizing you can find here: [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How ever, Im not sure where to apply the array to my code.

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Also, you have to have someplace where you set all the other variables for $property_city and everything else. Your code doesn't show that.

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean? As far as setting the keys to the fields?

Comment: So far I have your code working, I didnt validate or nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make any change to the form. You need to make a change in the theme's function to include a tax_query which will get multiple terms from your taxonomy property_type with a relation OR

```
 $s = $_GET['s'];
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
   if($key == 'property_type'){
    $item_property_type['taxonomy'] = htmlspecialchars($key);
    $item_property_type['terms'] = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $item_property_type['field'] = 'slug';
    $list[] = $item_property_type;
  }
}
$taxproperty_type = array_merge(array('relation' => 'OR'), $list);

                 $meta_query=array();
            if ($s == __('Search', 'framework')) {
                $query->set('s', '');
            }
              $query->set('post_type', 'property');
              $query->set('post_status','publish');
              if (!empty($property_type)) {
               $query->set('tax_query',$taxproperty_type);
                }
                if (!empty($property_city)) {
               $query->set('city-type',$property_city);
                }
if (!empty($property_neighborhood)) {
               $query->set('neighborhood',$property_neighborhood);
                }
              if (!empty($property_contract_type)) {
                 $query->set('property-contract-type', $property_contract_type);
                }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's now not respecting my query at all and when I search it shows all posts when I select any options. If i don't select anything from my drop down then it shows me the correct posts for the query.

Comment: I updated my question with the full code from my functions file.